# jquery load after load problem

Tags: jquery, load

I'm trying to develop a Categories Selector. It should be a jquery dialog(), e.g.

```
$("#CategoriesSelector").load(url).dialog({...})
```

The url - is a path to CategoriesSelector.php which loads categories. I have 2 levels of categories: 1st level - on left hand column and 2nd level - on right hand column.

If the 1st category is not selected, the script loads just 1st level categories.  When user clicks on a category - the 2nd level of selected category is loaded with jquery load() on the right hand column.

The problem is when the dialog() is opened with 1st level category selected! In this case the main content should to be loaded with load() and inside of the content another load() should to load the 2nd level categories. So, I have a load() which should to run another load(). The second load() doesn't work!

How can I fix this?

## Thanks!

E.g.
On the main file I have:

```
$("#CategoriesSelector").load(url).dialog({...})
```

The url loads a file (php) which has following code:

```
$('#CS_subcategoriesSelector').load(url);
```

This url - loads a php file which insert in the #CS_subcategoriesSelector the second level of categories.

IF the first url has the CategoryID variable (ID of the selected category from 1 level) - the second load() should to load automatically all sublevels of selected category with ID=CategoryID. THe second load() doesn't work!

Comment: Post more of your javascript, the part that loads the 2nd level

Answer (score 1):

is your "`$('#CS_subcategoriesSelector').load(url);`" in your document ready of the first version of the category screen?

or, you could put that in your success handler...

```
$("#CategoriesSelector").load(url, function(){
    if(categoryId != 0){
        $('#CS_subcategoriesSelector').load(url);
    }

}).dialog({...})
```